# First-countable topological spaces

Tags: general-topology, first-countable

So I have a topology defined as follows:
$$ \tau = \{\mathbb{R} \} \cup \{ U \subset \mathbb{R} \ \ | \ \ 0 \notin U \}$$

I have already prooved that is a topology of $\mathbb{R}$ and that the local basis of $x \in \mathbb{R}$ are defined by:

$\{\mathbb{R}\}$ if $x=0$ and $\{x\}$ if $x \neq 0$.

However I am having troubles trying to prove wether $(\mathbb{R}, \tau)$ is first-countable or not.

> **Context.-**
> I think that it is first-countable because every point in $\mathbb{R} $ has a countable neighbourhood basis, although I am not sure if this is correct because if $x =0$, is $\{\mathbb{R}\}$ countable?

Comment: $\{\mathbb R\}$ is finite.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable but $\{\mathbb{R}\}$ is finite since it is a singleton set. That should be the final nail in your solution.